# How to delete or replace empty space for the values like abc(396) to abc in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below table (Table1) and the SQL query where I'm trying to delete the numbers along with the parenthesis in the column1 and update the result values in column2.

```
Idnum  Column1         Column2
-------------------------------
1      imports(399)    imports
2      imports(400)    imports
3      imports(401)    imports
```

Code:

```
Update #Table1 
set Column2 = Replace((Select Column1 from #Table1 where IDNUM = 1),'()','')
where IDNUM = 1
```

I know the above code tries to replace it for only one column and even that is a wrong code (just shown as an example to give the idea).

How can I achieve the above process, the numbers can be of any digits here in the above example I have shown a 3 digit number.

Comment: Do the values in Column1 always follow the format 'imports(some number)'??

Comment: Thanks for the response.....It might be any string but the format is like "string ( any digit number)"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/938d3/4)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Idnum] int, [Column1] varchar(12), [Column2] varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Idnum], [Column1], [Column2])
VALUES
    (1, 'imports(399)', 'imports'),
    (2, 'imports(400)', 'imports'),
    (3, 'imports(401)', 'imports'),
        (3, 'imports', 'imports')
;
```

**Query 1**:
Run this to verify the output is acceptable:

```
select Column1
    ,case 
        when charindex('(', Column1) > 0
            then substring(Column1, 1, charindex('(', Column1) - 1)
        else Column1
        end as Column1Fixed
from Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/938d3/4/0)**:

```
|      Column1 | Column1Fixed |
|--------------|--------------|
| imports(399) |      imports |
| imports(400) |      imports |
| imports(401) |      imports |
|      imports |      imports |
```

So, you can run this to do the update:

```
update Table1 set Column2 = case 
        when charindex('(', Column1) > 0
            then substring(Column1, 1, charindex('(', Column1) - 1)
        else Column1
        end
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.  It will extract the value between two parentheses.

```
update #Table1
set Column2 = substring(Column1,charindex('(',Column1,1)+1,charindex(')',column1,1)-charindex('(',Column1,1)-1)
```